# React native 0.69.5, react-native-elements, Icon component showing just X

Tags: android, react-native, icons, react-native-elements

Tried both ways to show Icon:

- with `import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'`
- with `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'`

### Dependencies

[image: dependencies]

### import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

```js
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

<Icon
  raised
  name='heartbeat'
  type='font-awesome'
  color='#f50'
  onPress={() => console.log('hello')} />
```

### import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

<Input
  placeholder='INPUT WITH CUSTOM ICON'
  leftIcon={
    <Icon
      name='user'
      size={24}
      color='black'
    />
  }
/>
```

Also CheckBox shows an X instead of the usual

```js
<CheckBox
title="Remember me"
checked={false}/>
```

Showing:

[image: CheckBox showing X instead of the usual]

### What I tried

- [Edit app/build.gradle for manual linking `react-native-vector-icons`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1450)
- [I didn't understand this, do I have to download and load my icons/assets inside my project manually?](https://github.com/unimonkiez/react-native-asset#readme)

## Solved

Solved by manually copying [their folder](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/tree/master/Fonts) with all the ttf inside `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` as said [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-manually)

Answer (score 2):

If its on android you have to follow the following steps:
go into `android/app/build.gradle` and paste the below line at top.

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

After that you have to npx react-native run-android and it will show the icons.

Comment: This worked for me on react-native 0.67.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about elements, but for the vector icons, you just have to write like that :

```
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
```

then

```
<FontAwesome name="user" size={24} style={{color:'black'}} />
```

Comment: Not working :(
Shows always an X

Comment: Its working well for me.
did you follow all the installation instructions ?

Comment: It could be a problem that starts from react-native >= 0.69

Comment: I don't think so. Just follow all installation instructions. I know there is proper things to do for this react-native-vector-icons package